# Update table with myCon.query using an array of set values

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am trying to use an array of values to populate an escaped sql query.  The array being accepted.

I was using:

```
function genUpdateString(settings) {
  var sql = "";
  var first = true;
  for (attr in settings) {
    if (
      settings[attr] != undefined &&
      attr != "userid" &&
      attr != "api_key"
    ) {
      if (first) {
        first = false;
      } else {
        sql += ", ";
      }
      sql += attr + "='" + settings[attr] + "'";
    }
  }
  return sql;
}

sql_update = genUpdateString(...);

var sql = "UPDATE user SET " + sql_update + " WHERE name = '" + newSettings.userid + "'";  
myCon.query(sql, (err, result) => {
```

This works fine but when I tried to move to the escaped format it crashes:

```
var sql = "UPDATE user SET ? WHERE name = ?";  
myCon.query(sql, [sql_update, userid], (err, result) => {
```

When I create the string manually it runs through fine and updates my database tables but using the second method it crashes with the error:

> Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''age=\'33\'' WHERE name = 'Josephy Krakowski'' at line 1

Comment: The ? placeholder will quote the update fragment in `sql_update`. How are you generating `sql_update`?

Comment: I am using this function with req.body as settings: `function genUpdateString(settings) {
    var sql = ""
    var first = true;
    for (attr in settings) {
        if (settings[attr] != undefined && attr != "userid" && attr != "api_key") {
            if (first) {
                first = false
            } else {
                sql += ", "
            }
            sql += attr + "='" + settings[attr] + "'"   
        }
    }
    return sql
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `genUpdateString` function isn't SQL injection safe either – just adding single quotes isn't secure.

Something like this is – we're generating the query fragment with question marks and the args "in parallel".

```
function genUpdateAndArgs(map) {
  const names = [];
  const args = [];
  for(var key in map) {
    const value = map[key];
    if(value !== undefined) {
      names.push(key);
      args.push(value);
    }
  }
  // ['foo', 'bar'] => 'foo = ?, bar = ?'
  const namesFragment = names.map((name) => `${name} = ?`).join(', ');
  return [namesFragment, args];
}

const settings = {
  'foo': 123,
  'bar': 456,
};
const userId = 1337;

const [namesFragment, updateArgs] = genUpdateAndArgs(settings);
const query = `UPDATE user SET ${namesFragment} WHERE name = ?`;
const args = [].concat(updateArgs).concat(userId);
console.log(query, args);
```

The output is

```
UPDATE user SET foo = ?, bar = ? WHERE name = ?
[ 123, 456, 1337 ]
```

which you could then plug into `db.query`...

However I really heartily recommend a query builder like [Knex](http://knexjs.org/) instead – in Knex, the same would be approximately

```
knex('user')
  .where('name', userId)
  .update(settings)
```

Comment: I had the wrong idea of how the query works.  First timer.  i am checking out knex now.